# Is private Node head; and private Node head = null; the same thing?

Tags: java, null

Was looking through the LinkedList java class from my computer science class and I was wondering if declaring  `private Node head;` is the same thing as `private Node head = null;`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> **4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables**
>
> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is used:
>
> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
> - [...]
> - For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is `null`.

Since the default value of all objects is `null`, there is no difference.